# how to draw a custom UIView with a visible border and transparent interior (i.e. just draw the border)

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, transparency

The frame size is adjustable so using a png for background is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set background color of your view to clearColor, then either set border property to view's layer (see here [how-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330378/cocoa-touch-how-to-change-uiviews-border-color-and-thickness/3330397#3330397)), or in view's `drawRect:` method stroke a rectangular path on the border of the view