# Separating multiple UILabels with a line IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, cgcontextref

I wan to design a settings page, in which I have to draw lines between multiple labels, what is the best way to do this, I have googled around, got to know about `CGContextRef` approach. Is this the proper way, I need to have a line between labels (consecutively). Can I go ahead with this approach or any other best way is there.

Comment: Would you like to underline the text?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711297/underline-text-in-uilabel/2711587#2711587

Comment: For each separator line create a CALayer that is 1 pixel tall and set its background color.

Comment: Why dont you make a UITableView ?? I think for the Settings page Grouped TableView is being used :)

Comment: check this out - <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666863/uiview-bottom-border>

Comment: use UITableView, add labels inside the UITableView or you can use another label with a height of 1px between each label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given base view as dark color and I am adding labels as white, I am giving a line gap between two labels its looking like a line. No extra work :)

Answer (score 0):

May be just add UIView between labels? Something Like this:

```
UILabel *topLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 20)];
//Label settings
[self addSubview:topLabel];
[topLabel release];

UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(topLabel.frame.origin.x, CGRectGetMaxY(topLabel.frame), topLabel.frame.size.width, 2)];
separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UILabel *bottomLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(separator.frame), 320, 20)];
//Label settings
[self addSubview:bottomLabel];
[bottomLabel release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create a custom UIView class with a UILabel and a UIView as the subviews of this custom view class?

```
class CustomView : UIView
{
    UIView *line;
    UILabel *label;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *line;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
```

For the UIView subview, you can tell it to use the width of the parent UIView.