# Text Field with Only top and Bottom Border using swift 2

Tags: swift2, ios9

I have a page for forgot password. It has only a text field asking the user to fill in their email address. The Designer designed the text field with top and bottom border only. 
I tried answer from here [UITextField Only Top And Bottom Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562438/uitextfield-only-top-and-bottom-border)
but in the result it only shows bottom border for the text field.
[image]

Like in the image i would like to create a grey border for top and bottom

Comment: yes...for top border make another layer and set frame `CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @El Captain for the valuable comment and nice answer by @Bjorn Ro even if it was in Objective-c i think. 
And my answer for the question is (i'm using swift 2 Xcode 7)

Override the function viewDidLayoutSubviews() in your swift file. And the Code for the same is

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
// Creates the bottom border
        let borderBottom = CALayer()
        let borderWidth = CGFloat(2.0)
        borderBottom.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        borderBottom.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: forgotPasswordEmailText.frame.height - 1.0, width: forgotPasswordEmailText.frame.width , height: forgotPasswordEmailText.frame.height - 1.0)
        borderBottom.borderWidth = borderWidth
        forgotPasswordEmailText.layer.addSublayer(borderBottom)
        forgotPasswordEmailText.layer.masksToBounds = true

// Creates the Top border
        let borderTop = CALayer()
        borderTop.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        borderTop.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: forgotPasswordEmailText.frame.width, height: 1)
        borderTop.borderWidth = borderWidth
        forgotPasswordEmailText.layer.addSublayer(borderTop)
        forgotPasswordEmailText.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
```

forgotPasswordEmailText is the text field for entering Email

The Final output looks like this... with a gray Colour border (Screen shot of iPhone 4s Simulator)[image]

Comment: right, i forgott that iam on a swift2 tag ... sorry about that :D just saw the linked post and was adapting it ;)

Comment: @Björn Ro I thought about creating another layer and adding it. But as a developer from c# background and it's my first approach with Xcode and swift i was not sure about that.

Comment: Yeah, And Wish You guys will be here to answer more questions... ;)

Answer (score 5):

To remove Fights with views you could create a tableView with a static cell that contains a TextField. Voila done... Top and bottom border comes for free and you will use standard apple stuff :)

If you really want to draw the layers than follow the steps on your linked questions:

```
CALayer *topBorder = [CALayer layer];
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 1);
topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[myTextField.layer addSublayer:topBorder];

CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - 1, self.frame.size.width, 1);
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
[myTextField.layer addSublayer:bottomBorder];
```

In Swift:

```
let topBorder = CALayer()
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width, 1)
topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
textField.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)

let bottomBorder = CALayer()
bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, bounds.size.height-1, bounds.size.width, 1)
bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestions for programatic solution posted so far. But I figured I'd share an Interfacebuilder solution....

1) Create view collection in your view controller

```
 @IBOutlet private var borderViews: [UIView]?
```

2) Create 2 UIViews in interface builder 1px high constrained to where you want them around the textfield

3) Connect the 2 views in interface builder to borderViews IBOutlet

4) Customise appearance of both views by using setValue forKeyPath... for example, on success you may want the border to turn green

```
 setValue(UIColor.green, forKeyPath: "borderViews.backgroundColor")
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 use extension:

1. Create Swift file

   ```
   import UIKit

   extension UITextField {

       func setBottomBorder() {
           self.borderStyle = .none
           self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
           self.layer.masksToBounds = false
           self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
           self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.0)
           self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
           self.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
       }
   }
   ```
2. Call from anywhere:

   ```
   PasswordField.setBottomBorder();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice and easy Swift 4 implementation that handles resizing views as well :)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    viewToShadow.backgroundColor = .white
    viewToShadow.layer.masksToBounds = false

    viewToShadow.layer.sublayers?
        .filter { layer -> Bool in
            return layer.backgroundColor == UIColor.almostBlack.alpha(0.5).cgColor
        }
        .forEach { layer in
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    }

    [CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: viewToShadow.bounds.width, height: 0.5),
     CGRect(x: 0.0, y: viewToShadow.bounds.height, width: viewToShadow.bounds.width, height: 0.5)]
        .forEach { frame in
            let layer = CALayer()
            layer.frame = frame
            layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.almostBlack.alpha(0.5).cgColor
            viewToShadow.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use handy extension for it

```
extension UITextField {
    func addTopBorder(){
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1)
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

    }

    func addBottomBorder(){
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - 1, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 1)
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: self.placeholder ?? "-", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)])
        self.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

    }
}
```

use it in you controller like this

```
yourTextfield.addTopBorder()
yourTextfield.addBottomBorder()
```

and don't forget to use it on main thread

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.yourTextfield.addTopBorder()
           self.yourTextfield.addBottomBorder()
        }
```