# I need to validate text entered,if it's not in correct form it should be underlined in red and if correct should underline in green

Tags: ios, xcode, textfield

Thes is my code and i want to add underline part but i don't know how.

```
   #define ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS @"0123456789"


- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

if (textField==ucontact)
{        NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_CHARECTERS] invertedSet];

    NSString *filtered = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    return (([string isEqualToString:filtered])&&(newLength <= 10));

}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: you are add underline in design or coding?

Comment: Of course that's possible, just create an NSAttributedString with the properties you want (there are plenty of questions on SO for that) and set the text fields `attributedText` property.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through the work around. You can add one line with the help of UIView below the textField and name it as the validatorView and change the color of the line according to your wish after validation.

Hope this helps best luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15562438/uitextfield-only-top-and-bottom-border).  It illustrates how you can make use of only the bottom border.  Alternatively you can also add a line as a UIView subview.

I am curious why you do not use the Numpad keyboard.

`textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad` (Swift)