# How to set an upper border/separator line in ios?

Tags: objective-c, imageview, label, border, line

I have an imageview and a label, I want a border in between them, what is the best approach?

I know that the following code creates a border around the whole imageView:

```
[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

But I only want a line below it, not around the whole thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add an `UILabel` with background color as black(Assuming your border color as black) and height of 1px between you `UIImageView` and `UILabel` this would be much simpler.

Comment: That works, but I found this solution to be more elegant:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666863/uiview-bottom-border

Comment: It was just a tweak. though you can use `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` which I feel it is much faster than `UIKit`.