# Swift addsubview and remove it

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I want to add sub view and remove with one tap.
This is my code:

To add subview:

```
var testView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568))
testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
testView.alpha = 0.5
testView.tag = 100
super.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
self.view.addSubview(testView)
```

To remove subview:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let point = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    
    if(testView.tag==100){
        println("Tag 100")
        testView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    else{
        println("tag not found")
    }
}
```

But the remove it isn't working

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  The adding?  The removing?  Errors?  Please edit your question to include more information.

Comment: testView is the view with tag 100, not self.view, so your if statement is never executed.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Thanks for help. This is the solution:
I created the subview and i add a gesture to remove it

```
@IBAction func infoView(sender: UIButton) {
    var testView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568))
    testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    testView.alpha = 0.5
    testView.tag = 100
    testView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(testView)

    let aSelector : Selector = "removeSubview"
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: aSelector)
    testView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func removeSubview(){
    println("Start remove sibview")
    if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(100) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }else{
        println("No!")
    }
}
```

Update:

**Swift 3+**

```
@IBAction func infoView(sender: UIButton) {
    let testView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 568))
    testView.backgroundColor = .blue
    testView.alpha = 0.5
    testView.tag = 100
    testView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.view.addSubview(testView)

    let aSelector : Selector = #selector(GasMapViewController.removeSubview)
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: aSelector)
    testView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func removeSubview(){
    print("Start remove sibview")
    if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(100) {
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    }else{
        print("No!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 86):

You have to use the `viewWithTag` function to find the view with the given `tag`.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch
    let point = touch.locationInView(self.view)

    if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(100) {
        print("Tag 100")
        viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
    } else {
        print("tag not found")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! actually this solved my problem. But the interaction with de super view it doesn't disable. How can i disable the interaction with the super view?

Comment: I didn't understand. What interaction with superview?

Comment: I have a tap gesture in the first view, after with a button i add a subview, but is just a information view, so, with a tap a i want to remove it. Now it is working the remove tap. But in the first view i receive the same tap, i need to disable that tap... thanks!!

Comment: Where do you want to tap to remove the information view? Do you want to remove the  view when  the information view is tapped on the inside and not outside ?

Comment: Yes, when the user tap on the information view(second view), i want to remove that view(second view) and show the **first** view again.

Comment: Add a uitaprecognizer to the information view and use it to remove the view

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you have access to it via outlets or programmatic code, you can remove it by referencing your view `foo` and the `removeFromSuperview` method

```
foo.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 9):

I've a view inside my custom CollectionViewCell, and embedding a graph on that view. In order to refresh it, I've to check if there is already a graph placed on that view, remove it and then apply new. Here's the solution

```
cell.cellView.addSubview(graph)
graph.tag = 10
```

now, in code block where you want to remove it (in your case gestureRecognizerFunction)

```
if let removable = cell.cellView.viewWithTag(10){
   removable.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

to embed it again

```
cell.cellView.addSubview(graph)
graph.tag = 10
```

Answer (score -13):

**Tested this code using XCode 8 and Swift 3**

To Add Custom View to SuperView use:

`self.view.addSubview(myView)`

To Remove Custom View from Superview use:

`self.view.willRemoveSubview(myView)`

Comment: willRemoveSubview do not removes subview from the superview. It only tells when subview is about to be removed.

Comment: To remove custom view from superview one should use myView.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: willRemoveSubview do not removes subview from the superview.