# Create Vertical lines between Uilabels inside of a stack view

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uistackview

I want to create a UICollectionView with a custom header in Code. Therefore i created a  Subclass of UICollectionViewCell to describe my custom header. I want to display five labels in my header in a horizontal line. Therefore I created five labels and  add them inside a stackView. The stackview show my labels filled equally. So far everything perfect.

Label1  Label2  Label3  Label4   Label5

```
   //Label 1
    let votesLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Votes", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12) ])
    attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n 0", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGray, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]))
    label.attributedText = attributedText

    // label.text = "11\nvotes"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    return label
   }()


// label 2 ... 5



  // creating the subview and add the labels to my subview
        addSubview(topDividerView)
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [ votesLabel, and the other 4 labels])
       stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        addSubview(stackView)

   // add stackView to my view 

        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

Now I want to add separate vertical lines between these labels like that:

Label1 |  Label2    |   Label3   |   Label4  |   Label5

I created a UIView but can't add this view between the labels. Can anyone help me please. Thanks

Comment: I can't see any code where the separators are added to the StackView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211738/can-you-give-uistackview-borders

Comment: Thanks Brandon . So this means the UIstackview is a nonRendering view and it  can't be done.

Answer (score 6):

If you do that in interface builder it can be very easy. Add you labels to horizontal stack view, then add your divider views in between, create 1 point width constraint for your divider views, set their hugging priority higher than your labels and set your stack view's alignment to `fill` and distribution to `equal spacing`. That's it. You may also want to set the dividers' width constraint priority to 999 so the xcode wont complain for breaking constraints in some cases.

here're a screenshot of my quick test:
[image]

and the result in the simulator:
[image]

My example is done straight in a view of a view controller, but you of course can create a new UIView subclass with a xib file, put the labels (and dividers) in there and later instantiate your view something like this: `let myView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyViewWithLabels", owner: nil, options: nil)![0] as! MyViewWithLabels`. Then just add your view instance to your collection view cll as a subview.