# iOS layer masking doesn't work on UIStackView

Tags: ios, mask, layer, uistackview

I tried applying a layer mask in iOS (iOS12) on the layer of a UIStackView. The mask doesn't work and I still see the UIStackView whole.

Comment: I am pretty sure the base layer of a UIStackView is a CATransformLayer so properties such as mask to bounds border color and others won’t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you can't mask UIStackViews! When I wrapped the stack view in a regular UIView, and applied the mask on it - the masking started to work.

Comment: Detailed answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211738/can-you-give-uistackview-borders