# Draw border "within" UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I need to draw a visible border that goes around the edge of the screen within my view controller. I tried setting the view's borderWidth and borderColor, but nothing appeared on the screen. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Look at the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8197568/1891327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following code and it worked.

```
self.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orangeColor().CGColor
self.view.layer.borderWidth = 3
```

[image: ViewController]

Comment: Oh dear me, I wasn't using the .view nor .layer. Thank you!