# Different border colors on a uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i've created a collectionView with several cells. However i want to create a custom border where the border is one color and and rest of the sides is another color. How can i do that? So far i've just created a normal border in my cell subclass

```
//Cell
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(rgba: "#f2f2f2").CGColor
self.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Can't you just add a subview to the collection view? and pin it to the side with auto layout.

Comment: isnt there a better option with sublayers?

Comment: has answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666863/uiview-bottom-border