# How to apply top border on UILabel with autoresizingMask in iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel, calayer

I built a custom tableview with xib file. I added a `UILabel` with top border, code for top border is

```
UIView *topBorder = [UIView new];
topBorder.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.nameOfImage.frame.size.width, 1);
[cell.nameOfImage addSubview:topBorder];

cell.nameOfImage.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Auto resize is [image]

But its not resizing with screen differ as in 5s and 6s plus. It is not showing with `UILabel` size. In 5s

[image]

And in 6s Plus
[image]

The top border is not showing with respect to label.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666863/uiview-bottom-border/48109396#48109396

Answer (score 0):

You need to update width of `topBorder` according `cell.nameOfImage` width. Move your code for frame changing to `layoutSubviews`:

**Objective-C**:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    UIView *top = [[UIView alloc] init];
    topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, nameOfImage.frame.size.width, 1.0)
}
```

**Swift**:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, nameOfImage.frame.size.width, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give in objective c, i think i added same with respect to frame

Comment: you need to add constraint in xib file. Select top view and right drag to image view. Then you select equal width

Comment: @Irfan thanks for your reply I also test with constraint but same result.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov I have added the same code, But not solve.