# Rectangular Selection like in Windows Desktop

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm making a Schedule App for Cocoa Touch and I need to be able to select a time interval just by touching the screen. I mean, the user must be able to select with its fingers a time interval within the "ScheduleView" and then Add an event.

I was thinking of making some kind of rectangular selection, similar to the one that everyone can do in Windows Desktop, but i don't know how to detect multiple touches, neither how to draw the selection rectangle. Can anyone help me?

P.S: The "ScheduleView" it's a `UIView`, not a `UITableView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to your view. You can detect touches as a delegate, and this case will probably do best with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.  You'll set the delegate to be yourself and draw the box within `-(void)panGestureMoveAround:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture`  Here is a [tutorial](http://blog.shoguniphicus.com/2011/06/15/working-with-uigesturerecognizers-uipangesturerecognizer-uipinchgesturerecognizer/).

To draw the box, you could manually draw into the view but it may be easier to reshape a UIView on top and manipulate its border width and color like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330378/cocoa-touch-how-to-change-uiviews-border-color-and-thickness).