# Is there an easy way to add a border to a view in Xcode for iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, uiview, border

I'm looking to have a border around a `UIView` I have just to separate it from the main view visually.

I have looked in the settings for the `UIView` in storyboard editor but I can't seem to find anything for setting a border.

Is there an easy way to do this in code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Touch: How To Change UIView's Border Color And Thickness?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330378/cocoa-touch-how-to-change-uiviews-border-color-and-thickness)

Answer (score 29):

With Swift and XCode 6 you can do this.

Click the UIView element in Storyboard, and go to identity inspector. In the user defined runtime attributes, enter:

```
layer.borderWidth number 1
```

If you want nice looking corners

```
layer.cornerRadius number 5
layer.masksToBounds boolean true
```

Now this will give you a border but to set the colour you need to do it with code. Go to your view controller, and add an IBOutlet from your UIView. Say you do,

```
@IBOutlet weak var xView: UIView!
```

Call this in the viewDidLoad function like below to set the colour.

```
xView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
```

Thanks!

Comment: why do you have to define the color in code? There is the field `layer.borderColor color red`, but that does not work. Can you explain why?

Comment: I found a way how the color does update in storyboard :) See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29074130

Answer (score 1):

With this border, background still appears behind. In other words, the border isn't projected to outer of view, but to inner space.

I think that is necessary create a overlay view behind the owner with size (width  x height) increased with border size.