# How to set the custom border color of UIView programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set the custom border color of UIView programmatically in Swift.

Comment: Show the relevant code in your question. Explain what issue you are having.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa Touch: How To Change UIView's Border Color And Thickness?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330378/cocoa-touch-how-to-change-uiviews-border-color-and-thickness) you just need to use it in swifty way

Answer (score 227, accepted):

**If you Use Swift 2.0+**

```
self.yourView.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:222/255, green:225/255, blue:227/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
```

Comment: Note: this didnt seem to work for me (perhaps because I'm on swift 3.1?). Paras Joshi's (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29701061/225813) version did work though

Comment: I  edited my answer . it sure to work for you .. Ashley Coolman

Comment: You do not need to call init explicitly in swift 3.

Comment: Is it possible to use more than one color ?

Comment: Is there any difference between your two versions?

Comment: For me it was weird because I was doing this but in reverse order. It seems to matter and if you set the color before the border width it doesn't show. At least it seemed to be the case... All working now. I am calling layer.borderWidth inside a method on my custom view which has a xib.

Answer (score 97):

In **Swift 4** you can set the border color and width to UIControls using below code.

```
let yourColor : UIColor = UIColor( red: 0.7, green: 0.3, blue:0.1, alpha: 1.0 )
yourControl.layer.masksToBounds = true
yourControl.layer.borderColor = yourColor.CGColor
yourControl.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
```

**< Swift 4**, You can set UIView's border width and border color using the below code.

```
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 1

yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: @ShashiVerma you are welcome. For deep detail about layers, read apple's different object's class reference documents, so that is also helpful for you :)

Answer (score 17):

Use **@IBDesignable** and **@IBInspectable** to do the same.

They are re-useable, easily modifiable from the Interface Builder and the changes are reflected immediately in the Storyboard

Conform the objects in the storyboard to the particular class

Code Snippet:

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomView: UIView{

@IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0{

    didSet{

        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
    }
}


@IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {

    didSet {

        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
    }
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {

    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
}

}
```

**Allows easy modification from Interface Builder:**

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: I like this solution more since it is a reusable one where we set the UIView to the customview but still leaves room more changes.

Comment: This was my favorite way to achieve it but with dark mode, it doesnt really work well. It gets the color style of current MacOS and uses static. But build in `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` all works well, so there should be a way for customs to use Color Assets with both dark/light mode too~ anyone knows how can achieve it?

Answer (score 15):

You can write an extension to use it with all the UIViews eg. UIButton, UILabel, UIImageView etc.
You can customise my following method as per your requirement, but I think it will work well for you.

```
extension UIView{

    func setBorder(radius:CGFloat, color:UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()) -> UIView{
        var roundView:UIView = self
        roundView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(radius)
        roundView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        roundView.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
        roundView.clipsToBounds = true
        return roundView
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
btnLogin.setBorder(7, color: UIColor.lightGrayColor())
imgViewUserPick.setBorder(10)
```

Comment: @luda i don't think he/she has much of a choice about the api language!

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 5.2**, **UIView+Extension**

```
extension UIView {
    public func addViewBorder(borderColor:CGColor,borderWith:CGFloat,borderCornerRadius:CGFloat){
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWith
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = borderCornerRadius

    }
}
```

You used this extension;

```
yourView.addViewBorder(borderColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.6, green: 0.6, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1), borderWith: 1.0, borderCornerRadius: 20)
```

Comment: you missed to add

    clipsToBounds = true

Answer (score 8):

swift 3

```
func borderColor(){

    self.viewMenuItems.layer.cornerRadius = 13
    self.viewMenuItems.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.viewMenuItems.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We can create method for it. Simply use it.

```
public func createBorderForView(color: UIColor, radius: CGFloat, width: CGFloat = 0.7) {
    self.layer.borderWidth = width
    self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = false
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = 2
    self.clipsToBounds = true
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    let cgColor: CGColor = color.cgColor
    self.layer.borderColor = cgColor
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.0

```
       groundTrump.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: Instead of adding a new answer, you must have sent an edit request to the original answerer

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Please no. Don't add code to other people's answers. Updates should be posted as their own, not into other answers. That way each poster is responsible for what they post...

Comment: @EricAya it's not about updating the answer. It is an edit request, may be in comments to the answerer. Did you got what I was trying to convey.

Answer (score 3):

Write the code in your `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.view.layer.borderColor = anyColor().CGColor
```

And you can set `Color` with `RGB`

```
func anyColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Learn something about `CALayer` in `UIKit`

Comment: Somehow, it does nothing unless you explicitly set the border width too.

Comment: @NicolasMiari that would be expected... you can't see a border colour you haven't set a size for.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was referring to text fields... which do seem to have a default non-zero border width from the start. However, I struggled to get the color I set reflected, until I explicitly set the border width.

Answer (score 3):

**swift 3.0**

```
self.uiTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    self.txtItemShortDes.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:205.0/255.0, green:205.0/255.0, blue:205.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Answer (score 2):

***Swift 5****

I, always use view extension to make view corners round, set border color and width and it has been the most convenient way for me. just copy and paste this code and controlle these properties in attribute inspector.

```
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderWidth: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor: color)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
            } else {
                layer.borderColor = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with the layers you can give border like this....
if not sometime you might have to true the wantslayer like **self.anytextField.wantslayer = true**

```
var BackgroundColor : CGColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
subLayer.shadowColor = self.BackgroundColor
subLayer.borderColor = self.BackgroundColor
subLayer.borderWidth = CGFloat(4)
```

or you can use the extension of CA Layer for macOS

```
func addBorder(edge: NSRectEdge, color: NSColor, thickness: CGFloat) {

    let border = CALayer()

    switch edge {
    case NSRectEdge.maxY:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: thickness)

    case NSRectEdge.minY:
        border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: frame.height - thickness, width: frame.width, height:thickness)

    case NSRectEdge.minX:
        border.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)

    case NSRectEdge.maxX:
        border.frame = CGRect(x: frame.width - thickness, y: 0, width: thickness, height: frame.height)

    default: do {}
    }

    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor

    addSublayer(border)
 }
```

**its usage is given below**

```
subLayer.addBorder(edge: <#T##NSRectEdge#>, color: <#T##NSColor#>, thickness: <#T##CGFloat#>)
```