# Button border color - Objective C - Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, layout

I want to change my border color to a specific hex color(#21CE99), can you guys please help me?

I've already known how to change it to a basic color, for example:

```
_button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

but I only need this color.

Thank you.

**Answer**

[How to set the custome border color of UIView programmatically in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29700919/how-to-set-the-custome-border-color-of-uiview-programmatically-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0 / 255.0 green:206.0 / 255.0 blue:153.0 / 255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer for people using **SWIFT 4** would be:

```
_button.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 33/255, green: 206/255, blue: 153/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
```

Built-In UIColors Presets or your own colors:

```
_button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

Answer (score 1):

easier

```
_button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x21 / 255.0 green:0xce / 255.0 blue:0x99 / 255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```