# Rounder border for cells in calendar FSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I am trying to add border each UIView. The first and the last selected dates should have rounded corners but the masking applied by the rounded corners extension is cropping it out.

I have tried many other solutions but this one seems to be the closest to be true.

Excuse my bad english.

```
extension FSCalendarCell {

    func changeCellStyle(isSelected:Bool, firstIndex:Bool, lastIndex:Bool, color:UIColor){

        let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: self.bounds.width,height: self.bounds.height))

        v.center = self.contentView.center
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        if firstIndex {
            v.addBorder(edges: [.top,.bottom,.left], color: UIColor.blue, thickness: 2)
            v.roundCorners([.topLeft, .bottomLeft], radius: 10)
        }else if lastIndex {
            v.addBorder(edges: [.top,.bottom,.right], color: UIColor.blue, thickness: 2)
            v.roundCorners([.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 10)
        }else{
            v.addBorder(edges: [.top,.bottom], color: UIColor.blue, thickness: 2)
        }

        self.contentView.insertSubview(v, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: please attach screen shot

Comment: Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330378/cocoa-touch-how-to-change-uiviews-border-color-and-thickness

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa Touch: How To Change UIView's Border Color And Thickness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330378/cocoa-touch-how-to-change-uiviews-border-color-and-thickness)

Comment: @Maulikshah https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2pWWIHUBc1HZUVTSHY4RkEtSDA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
v.layer.cornerRadius = v.frame.size.width/2
v.layer.maskToBounds = true
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this:

```
self.(calendar).clipsToBounds
```